# Modify Magento core behavior of item options storage of a product when it is inserted into its database

Tags: php, magento

My products in Magento have an item option that is stored in “sales_flat_quote_item_option” as soon as I add the product to the card. This happens when I select this option for the product and I add the product to that cart.

I want to know where exactly in Magento's core code is that item option inserted into that table so I can do some extra code there I want to do. Specifically, I want to save the data in that item option as a file as well.

Where can I see this behavior so I can write some more code in there and change it up a bit?

If I am not clear, please ask for more information. It was kind of complex to describe.

I found this interesting site which MAY be what I am looking for:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

Answer (score 1):

You could use help of Magento event-observer functionlity.

Hopefully this can help!

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Let me know if you need more help on this!